# Why Doesn't Backbone View Detect Model Changes?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I have the following Backbone.js model and collection:

```
// Model 
lr.Event = Backbone.Model.extend({});

// Collection
lr.Events = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: lr.Event,
  initialize: function(models, options) {
    this.date = options.date;
  },
  url: function() {
    return '/events' + '?date=' + this.date.toString('yyyy-MM-dd');
  }  
});
```

Which are used with a View and its sub-view:

```
// View
lr.MapView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $('#wrapper'),
  initialize: function() {
    this.date = this.options.date;
    _.bindAll(this, "render", "addAllEvents", "addOneEvent", "showNextDay", "collectData");
    this.collectData();
  },
  events: {
    "click #next": "showNextDay",
  },
  collectData: function() {
    var that = this;
    if (this.collection) this.collection.reset();
    this.collection = new lr.Events([], { date : this.date });
    this.collection.fetch({
      success:  function(resp) {
        that.render();
        that.addAllEvents();
      }
    });      
  },
  showNextDay: function() {
    this.date = this.date.add(1).days();
    this.collectData();
  },
  addAllEvents: function() {
    this.collection.each(this.addOneEvent);
  },
  addOneEvent: function(e) {
    var ev = new lr.EventView({ 
      model:  e,
      parentView: this
    });
  },
  ...
});

// Sub-view
lr.EventView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    var that = this;
    this.model.bind('change', function() {
      console.log('foo');
      that.remove();
    });
  }
  ...
});
```

I am trying to bind the sub-view to changes to its associated model.  So I would expect that when I call `this.collection.reset()`, `console.log('foo')` would be called.  But it is not.  I have `console.log`ed the collection before and I after I reset it, and it is definitely going from "something to nothing," so I assume I am somehow messing up the binding of the sub-view to the model.

Anyone see the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `reset()` with no models empties the collection, but does not **'change'** the existing models. The **'change'** event occurs when some attribute of the model [changes](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-set). Calling `reset()` does trigger the **'reset'** event on the collection itself (also triggered when you fetch a collection); when this is fired, you should also reset your UI, creating and rendering all the sub-view items `(in your case, it looks like you would call render and addAllEvents when you get the reset event)`.

```
this.collection.on('reset', this.removeExistingEventViewsThenAddAllEvents, this);
```

Now, when some attribute of an Event model does change, you ***will*** hit your change handler:

```
this.model.bind('change', function() {
  console.log('foo');
  that.remove();
});
```

But, I really doubt you want to remove the Event view when the model changes.  More likely, you want to re-render it, or update some part of it using JQuery.

Comment: Makes complete sense.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`collection.reset()` (`backbone.js` v0.91, line 609) only fires a `reset` event after silently removing and optionally repopulating the collection.

`collection.remove( model(s) );` (line 548) triggers a `remove` event on each model, so you could use
`collection.remove( collection.models );` to trigger the `remove` event on each model.

Comment: The backbone docs say "Calling `collection.reset()` without passing any models as arguments will empty the entire collection".  If the entire collection is emptied, doesn't that mean all the models would be deleted, and thus changed? http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-reset

Comment: Well, the source code seems to do what I described above. Maybe it worths a bug report/feature suggestion to the backbone team.